# Can't get object with ajax get from controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, get

I'm trying to return an object as json to my js. The error event is firing with a parseerror. What is the problem here?

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '/something/getmessage',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                },
                error: function (model, response) {
                }
            });
```

Controller method:

```
            [HttpGet] [Route("")]
            public NewsMessage GetMessage()
            {
                return messageObj; //Object is correct
            }
```

Error:
statusText:"OK"
status:200
"parsererror"

Comment: Could you please include the error here? Please include your sever side implementation for getmessage action method

Comment: Will show in original post

Comment: Could you please include the code including the controller class, error you are getting and your route settings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying your controller like this:

```
[HttpGet] [Route("")]
public JsonResult GetMessage()
{
    //code to form messageObj
    return Json(messageObj, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```